# Monitor doesn't detect any video signal

Tags: display, graphics-card

My old monitor keeps blinking when I power it on, (it doesn't sow anything) just the green light blinks and nothing happens,

But when i connect it to my other computer, It works perfectly..., So there is probably some problem with my Old computer.

Can any of you guys suggest what might be the problem??

Comment: I think you need your terms right...CPU stands for Central Processing Unit, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit . I think you wanted to say, that there's no graphical output on your old PC, which leads to the next question, OnBoard or external graphics card?

Comment: It might be worth commenting on what exactly you mean with "CPU" as you seem to misunderstand what it is. Typically, a CPU is a single chip inside your computer. I guess with "CPU" you mean that grey box that stands below/on your desk? That is what you would normally call "computer".

Comment: exact duplicate of [Monitor doesn't detect cpu, What might be the possible causes](http://superuser.com/questions/177245/monitor-doesnt-detect-cpu-what-might-be-the-possible-causes)

Comment: It is exact duplicate of [Monitor doesn't detect cpu, What might be the possible causes](http://superuser.com/questions/177236/monitor-doesnt-detect-cpu-what-might-be-the-possible-causes), I voted to close that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing could be a dead video card.  It might be worth trying to change your current card or attempting to SSH (Linux) or TSC (Windows) into your old machine and make sure the OS is at least okay.

Comment: Awesome.  Getting down voted for trying to help...  what a great forum.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the graphics card does not sit tight in its slot. If you have a dedicated graphics card, unmount it and replace it into the pci slot (or whatever slot it is made for).

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think the RAM in your CPU is loose. Just open the CPU cabinet and tightly fix the RAM (assuming you know where the RAM will be fit) and check again.

Comment: Might help trying to bend the network card somewhat. Not too much though. (The network card is the biggest card inserted into a slot in your hard drive.)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the plug connection may be loose on your computers. Have you tried a different monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Try disconecting all the ram slots, the 3V battery and the vga graphics card, wait a couple of minutes to the BIOS get erase, put the battery again in the cpu, then turn it on the computer without the ram or the vga card, the cpu must start to beep ( http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm ) the error must be from ram (3 beeps), turn the computer off, then put the ram back in, and turn it on again, now it must beep like an vga error, turn the computer off, put the vga back in and turn it on the cpu again, it must work fine now.

If it doesn't, try with another vga card.

good luck!